# How to change the JS function with extra inline code without editing the original files in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I wanted to change the logo image when scroll down with the code below, but it was hard to find and fix the original JS code within Shopify.
I have tried to add this code in the header section or theme.liquid file, but it did not working.
How and I make this working in Shopify theme?

```
var initialSrc = "...logo1;
var scrollSrc = "...logo2";

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var value = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (value > 90)
      $(".logo-image").attr("src", scrollSrc);
   else
      $(".logo-image").attr("src", initialSrc);
});
```

Comment: it should be theme.js or theme.min.js in your asset folder, check the theme.liquid file to see if which included

Comment: are you sure the IMG changed from JS code, or there is some code that is hide/show on certain conditions using JS?